# Change values of text area

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is a text-area where user put some text with 'new lines character', for example:

```
aaa
bbb

ccc
```

I would like to copy the value from this textarea to the input but there is a need to keep an information about new lines.

I want to replace new lines with some special separator like `NEW_LINE` and then decode it on the backend but something doesn't work, my code is:

```
var valueFromTextarea = $("#myTextarea").val();
valueFromTextarea .replace(/\n/g,"NEW_LINE");
$("#myTextarea-input").val(valueFromTextarea );
```

for this code the value of `myTextarea-input` is just `aaabbbccc`.

How is it possible to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method **returns** the modified value. It doesn't mutate the string (strings are immutable).

You need to pass its **return** value to `val()`.